# Unable to run php artisan test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am currently trying to run the command `php artisan test` which should run the test suite however I get the following error

```php
user@earth:/var/www/project/api$ art test -vvv

   ErrorException 

  Object of class Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse could not be converted to int

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136
    132▕     protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    133▕     {
    134▕         $method = method_exists($this, 'handle') ? 'handle' : '__invoke';
    135▕ 
  ➜ 136▕         return (int) $this->laravel->call([$this, $method]);
    137▕     }
    138▕ 
    139▕     /**
    140▕      * Resolve the console command instance for the given command.

  1   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}()

  2   vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:312
      Illuminate\Console\Command::execute()

  3   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:120
      Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run()

  4   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1022
      Illuminate\Console\Command::run()

  5   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:314
      Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand()

  6   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:168
      Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun()

  7   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:102
      Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run()

  8   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:129
      Illuminate\Console\Application::run()

  9   artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Given the error is internal to Laravel and the stacktrace all points to the Laravel vendor directory, how do you go about fixing something like this? I currently only have the 2 example tests that ship `tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php` and `tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php`.

I did recently upgrade to Laravel 9 but I couldn't see anything in the upgrade notes relating to this

My `composer.json` is as follows

```json
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.1.4",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.258",
    "cmgmyr/messenger": "^2.16",
    "creativeorange/gravatar": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^3.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4",
    "intervention/image": "^2.7",
    "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
    "laravel/framework": "v9.9.0",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.5",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.7.2",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.3.0",
    "mews/purifier": "^3.3.7",
    "nopjmp/discord-webhooks": "^0.3.1",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^2.12.0",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5",
    "spatie/laravel-sluggable": "^3.4",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.6",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
    "pestphp/pest-plugin-laravel": "^1.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
      "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": [
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
      "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
      "php artisan ide-helper:meta"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
      "php-http/discovery": true
    }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @KoalaYeung 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems not be of Laravel 9. Try deleting Vendor folder and removing composer.lock and then run composer install again.

The below is code of execute() method in Laravel 9:

```
 /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface  $input
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface  $output
     * @return int
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if ($this instanceof Isolatable && $this->option('isolated') !== false &&
            ! $this->commandIsolationMutex()->create($this)) {
            $this->comment(sprintf(
                'The [%s] command is already running.', $this->getName()
            ));

            return (int) (is_numeric($this->option('isolated'))
                        ? $this->option('isolated')
                        : self::SUCCESS);
        }

        $method = method_exists($this, 'handle') ? 'handle' : '__invoke';

        try {
            return (int) $this->laravel->call([$this, $method]);
        } finally {
            if ($this instanceof Isolatable && $this->option('isolated') !== false) {
                $this->commandIsolationMutex()->forget($this);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I deleted composer.lock and vendor yet after installing it still appears, I checked the 9.x branch and you are correct, it isn't apart of the repo. So I upgraded to 10.x and I'm still having an issue with converting to int despite the code being the same as what you posted so i'll try and dig into it more, I'm completely stumped as to why this is happening though

Comment: It's strange. Can you show tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php?

Comment: After much debugging and questioning I found that there was a command called Test in the tests directory. Given the error had no indication of that it completely slipped my mind to check, I feel incredibly dumb now